# run two thread at the same time in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i have used timertask to schedule my java program. now when the run method of timertask is in process, i want to run two threads which run at the same time and do different functions. here is my code.. please help me..

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class timercheck extends TimerTask{
// my first thread
Thread t1 = new Thread(){
     public void run(){
        for(int i = 1;i <= 10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }           
     }
 };

// my second thread
Thread t2 = new Thread(){
     public void run(){
        for(int i = 11;i <= 20;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }           
     }
 };

public static void main(String[] args){
      long ONCE_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24;

     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 05);
     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
     Date time = calendar.getTime();

     TimerTask check  = new timercheck();
     Timer timer = new Timer();
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(check, time ,ONCE_PER_DAY);
}

@Override    
// run method of timer task
public void run() {
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
}
```

Comment: So what is the current behavior?  What errors or output are you seeing?

Comment: currently both the threads are running one after another.. my prupose is to run them at the same time

Comment: @user1805005 : I don't think it is possible. whether to run a thread at the same time(in a multiprocessor/distributed system) is completely OS specific. you cannot force OS to do that. the least you can do is to assign priority to your threads but, this doesn't ensure their parallel execution.

Comment: BhavikShah thanku for the reply... but is der no method which can run them at the same time??

Comment: You can only control the lifecycle of the thread upto the OS thread scheduler.This is done by calling the `start()` method of the thread and putting it into the Runnable state. After that its entirely upto the OS to decide which thread runs first, second or last.

Comment: I think you're sample size is to small.  I ran it up to 5000 and threw in a random delay and had both of them out putting together.  Another problem may be the way that System.out works as well as the fact that all threads are at the same priority levels.

Comment: @MadProgrammer this was the dummy program, i have to do this for lakhs of lines, and so i was confused about the behaviour of thread execution. i am still not sure whether they will run parallely or not.

Comment: @user1805005 That's fine, I appreciate that, the statement though comes down to what the thread scheduler decides.  For your example, you need to increase the sample so that the scheduler will want to intervene and give some other threads a chance to complete.

Comment: @MadProgrammer so that means the scheduler will run the first thread and in between will give chance to the second thread and then will run the first thread.....?

Comment: @Nikki It's depended on the implementation, but that's the idea. Most OS's use a preemptive thread model, basically taking back control and giving it to some other thread as they see fit.  When I ran up you sample out put 5000, I was able to get the two threads to interweave, even though one might have had a head start

Comment: You can control which threads execute first with the `thread.join()` as explained here: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-threads-join-method.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i want to run two threads which run at the same time and do different functions.

I think your threads *are* running at the "same" time.  But because of race conditions, the first thread is just queueing its output before the 2nd.  You will not see one line from thread-1 and then 1 line from thread-2.  You will see blocks from one and then the other depending on the thread scheduling.

If you increase the amount of output from 10 lines to (for example) 1000, you should see that they are both running concurrently with interlaced output.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, I tested it in a compiler (and [on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/d6cWMV)). Even with the small inputs, on about 1/10 test runs, the two were interwoven at some point.

Comment: i changed the values (1 to 1000) and (1100 to 2000), and tested the program. first output was from 1 to 452 followed by 1100 to 2000 and then 453 to 1000....

Answer (score 4):

Make use of a CountDownLatch if you want to start both threads at the same time.

Since you have the above code t1 becomes eligible to Run (Runnable) before t2. So it is upto Java Scheduler to select whether to intermix t1 and t2 or finish t1 first and then t2. But if you want both t1 and t2 wait for a cue to begin execute, CountDownLatch can help you with that.

```
public class timercheck extends TimerTask{

private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch  = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // my first thread
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
         public void run(){

            countDownLatch.await();  

            for(int i = 1;i <= 10;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }           
         }
     };

    // my second thread
    Thread t2 = new Thread(){

         public void run(){

            countDownLatch.await();

            for(int i = 11;i <= 20;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }           
         }
     };

        public void run() {
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
```

For more information about CountDownLatch, Semaphore and CyclicBarrier read [this](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/comparison-of-countdownlatch.html) post.

Comment: This solution doesn't solve anything.  The first thread to run is going to be first to procede.  But whatever @user1805005.

Comment: @shazin i tried this code but it is doing the same thing.. it runs the first thread first and in between runs the second thread, and then the first..

Comment: @Nikki The code does run (start execute) the two threads at the same time. Seems like your requirement is not starting the two threads at the same time. May be you want to see an output like this?

thread-1 : Value x
thread-2 : Value x
thread-1 : Value x
thread-2 : Value x

Comment: @shazin so that means the two threads are running independently and are processing at the same time. am i right?

Comment: @Nikki Independently Yes, Sametime No. At a given time only one thread can run in a process. Explain your requirement a bit more.

Comment: my requirement is, when the run method of timertask is called, thread1 and thread 2 start running, independently. i dont want the first thread to stop in between to give second thread a chance to start, and when the second thread ends then the first thread resumes. i want them to do there own process without intervention.